# Python: Pivot tabel based on month in a date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot, pandas-groupby

I want tot pivot my tabel based on a month in a date.

Expected example result:

```
    jul,revenue,aug,revenue,sept,revenue,okt,revenue,nov,revenue,dec,revenue,jan,revenue,feb,revenue,mar,revenue,apr,revenue,may,revenue,jun,revenue
Jul-2017,1000,Aug-2017,1000,Sep-2017,1000,Oct-2017,1000,Nov-2017,1000,Dec-2017,1000,Jan-2018,1000,Feb-2018,1000,Mar-2018,1000,Apr-2018,1000,May-2018,1000,Jun-2018,1000
Jul-2018,1000,Aug-2018,1000,Sep-2018,1000,Oct-2018,1000,Nov-2018,1000,Dec-2018,1000,Jan-2019,1000,Feb-2019,1000,Mar-2019,1000,Apr-2019,1000,May-2019,1000,Jun-2019,1000
Jul-2019,1000,Aug-2019,1000,Sep-2019,1000,Oct-2019,1000,Nov-2019,1000,Dec-2019,1000,Jan-2020,1000,Feb-2020,1000,Mar-2020,1000,Apr-2020,0,May-2020,0,Jun-2020,0
```

I Tryed it with this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
df = pd.read_excel (r'examplefile')
ndf = df[['Saleprice', 'Date' , 'Season', 'Area', 'Place', 'Bookingsnumber']].reset_index(drop=True)
ndf['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ndf['Date'])

#Revenue per Year/Month
ndf['my'] = ndf['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%Y'))
grouped_ndf = ndf.groupby('my').sum().reset_index()
print(grouped_ndf)
```

The console gave me this result:

```
            my  Saleprice
0  01/2019       2000
1  01/2020       3000
2  02/2019       4000
3  02/2020       6000
```

Example file:

```
Saleprice,Date,Season,Area,Place,Bookingsnumber,Buy
1000,1-1-2019,winter 2019/2020,Zillertal,Mayrhofen,C20015243,800
1000,3-2-2019,winter 2019/2020,Zillertal,Königsleiten,B20015245,800
1000,5-2-2019,winter 2019/2020,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,C20015246,800
1000,1-1-2020,winter 2019/2020,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,D20015248,800
1000,3-2-2020,winter 2019/2020,Les Trois Vallées,Val Thorens,C20015249,800
1000,5-2-2020,winter 2019/2020,Zillertal,Königsleiten,C20015251,800
1000,1-1-2019,winter 2019/2020,Zillertal,Königsleiten,C20015252,800
1000,3-2-2019,winter 2019/2020,Espace Killy - Tignes,Tignes-Les-Brévières,C20015250,800
1000,5-2-2019,winter 2019/2020,Zillertal,Gerlos,B20015253,800
1000,1-1-2020,winter 2020/2021,Les Trois Vallées,Les Menuires,C20015254,800
1000,3-2-2020,winter 2020/2021,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,B20015255,800
1000,5-2-2020,winter 2020/2021,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,D20015256,800
1000,1-1-2020,winter 2020/2021,Les Trois Vallées,Les Menuires,E20015254,800
1000,3-2-2020,winter 2020/2021,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,B20015255,800
1000,5-2-2020,winter 2020/2021,Zell am See / Kaprun,Zell am See,B20015256,800
```

What do i have to change to get my example result? Looking forward to your response.

Comment: I didn't see where would 2017 come from since all your data is from 2019/2020

Comment: You are right. Its a bigger example :) with the example file you only get dates in 2019/2020. The principal is the same ( column jan + year, saleprice, column feb + year, saleprice). Do you have a sollution? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job, it is not the most pythonic one but it was all I could think:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
months = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b')).unique()
df['my'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b/%Y'))
dfgrouped = df.groupby('my')['Saleprice'].sum().reset_index()
month_dfs = [*map(lambda x: dfgrouped[dfgrouped['my'].str[:3]==x].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'my': x, 'Saleprice': 'revenue'}), months)]
new_df = pd.concat(month_dfs, axis=1)
```

Note that pd.to_datetime considers the first number in the Date column as the month, if you want the second number to be the month, you have to do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
months = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b')).unique()
df['my'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b/%Y'))
dfgrouped = df.groupby('my')['Saleprice'].sum().reset_index()
month_dfs = [*map(lambda x: dfgrouped[dfgrouped['my'].str[:3]==x].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'my': x, 'Saleprice': 'revenue'}), months)]
new_df = pd.concat(month_dfs, axis=1)
```

If you want to sort the months:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y'))
months_in_df = months = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b')).unique()
months = []
for i in range(1,13):
    if datetime.date(2020, i, 1).strftime('%b') in months_in_df:
        months.append((i, datetime.date(2020, i, 1).strftime('%b')))

df['my'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b/%Y'))
dfgrouped = df.groupby('my')['Saleprice'].sum().reset_index()
month_dfs = [*map(lambda x: dfgrouped[dfgrouped['my'].str[:3]==x].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'my': x, 'Saleprice': 'revenue'}), months)]
new_df = pd.concat(month_dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: thnx for your reply! I use your 2nd script. A few questions:
- what is the effect of * map
- what does 'str[:3]==x]' do? 
- When i extend my example file with a date in every month and `print(new_df)`, The console shows me the result in the following order: may, feb,jan,sep, dec, jun, jul, aug, oct, nov. How can is sort this from jan to dec in chronological order? 

Looking forward to your answer. Jeroen

Comment: map applies a function in a list of elements, in this case, months, it is just another way to avoid a for loop. str[:3] is the abbreviation of the month, so I am basically getting the data frames from a specific month, without worrying about the year. I guess you can sort them by sorting the month list, I will add another code so you can try a see if works.

Comment: Thnx for your quick reply @BrunoMello . Your new piece of code gave me an error in line 2: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp`. How to solve? Cheers.

Comment: i did. It gave me the same error. I put this piece of code above your last script:

`import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:examplefile.xlsx')`

Comment: Hopefully, you have some time to answer my question? 

I use the first number in the Date column as the month. Your last code doesn't. It uses the second number to be the month. I guess the problem is solved when you rewrite your last code where the first number is the month. Can you do this for me?

Comment: In the strptime you can change the %d-%m-%Y by the way your date is formatted, thus if it is for example month-year-day you can just do %m-%Y-%d or if it is month-day-year %m-%d-%Y. I have edited the code to be that way, did it solved now?

Comment: Thnx for your answer. Not yet. See de warning from my console below:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jeroe/Desktop/python/omzet_rev_month.py", line 7, in <module>
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y'))
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer`

Comment: second part error message:

`File "c:/Users/jeroe/Desktop/python/omzet_rev_month.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y'))
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp`

Comment: It is because you ran the code twice and thus `df['Date']` was already datetime, can you run it from the very start?

Comment: i cant solve it. Can you check my google colab: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mQkZXDOwztWZBGt5O3REyUU3Kz6uOH61)

Comment: did you found the bug in my Google colab? Thnx in advance.